# Why does otg mount take long time on some mobiles? Can it be sped up?

Tags: usb-on-the-go

I have an external 500GB SSD drive. I connected it to android devices via otg cable.

It works fine. Once it's mounted, it's pretty fast.

The only problem is the mounting time. At some devices, the mounting time is fast and about 6 seconds. This is fine to me. But at some devices, the mounting time will take up to 50 seconds. They are all running Android 10 with different models and brands.

I am wondering why the moutning times are so different among devices and is that possible to speed up the speed on the slow devices (without root).

Thank you very much.

**Edited:**

Some more information:

The `LOST.DIR` folder will be created at the first time mount.

The partition map/scheme is Master Boot Record.

The file system is FAT32. The reason why I don't use exfat is because some mobiles do not support exfat.

It doesn't matter what files inside the drive, the mounting time will not change. Even with a empty drive, the slow mobiles will still take about 50 seconds to mount. (so far).

For instance, for one slow mobile which is Sony brand. It can mount the drive really fast when it's exfat file system. I forgot to count the time, might be less than 10 seconds. But when it's fat32, it will take about 50 seconds to mount. I can not test it again because I have put data in the drive. If it's not necessary, I don't want to cut them out and reformat.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would assume that most users only have one Android device, hence they don't notice the different mount speeds. It would be interesting if you could add the details to your question which device requires what amount of time and how many files of what type are on the ORG stick.

Comment: @Robert thanks for your reply. The slow one is Sony brand. Sorry that I don't really want to reveal all the detial models. What inside the OTG stick does not matter. Even if the OTG is empty and mounting time will not change. The file system is fat32. The `LOST.DIR` folder will be created automatically after mount. For this Sony mobile, it takes about 50 seconds to mount the disk when it's fat32. But it will take a much less time to mount, when it's exfat. I forgot to count the time when it's exfat, it might be less than 10 seconds. I can not really test it now, because my drive has data now.

Comment: `logcat` usually helps.